# How to configure Password reset tokenlifespan in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, password-recovery

For my application i implemented ASP.NET Core Identity. I generate a password reset token with GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(). It works fine if i reset the password within 1 Day. After 1 Day it won't work anymore. i Get a 'invalid token' message. I already setted the TokenLifeSpan in the DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions to Timespan.FromDays(3), but that still doesnt seem to work.

But if i change my password within, it does work. Can someone help me because i'm really stuck with this issue. thankyou.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DUMMY_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DUMMY_DBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the codes about how you generate the forgotpassoword token?

Comment: var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, code, model.wachtwoord); 
 @BrandoZhang

Comment: @BrandoZhang any idea?